# How to define an array or vector that can contain any primitive data type in rust?

Tags: rust

How to define an array or vector that can contain any primitive data type in rust?

```
let v: [std::any::Any] = <something>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1 (faster + safer)

```
enum Data {
    Usize(usize),
    U8(u8),
    U16(u16),
    U32(u16),
    U64(u16),

    Isize(isize),
    I8(i8),
    I16(i16),
    I32(i16),
    I64(i16),

    F32(f32),
    F64(f64),

    Bool(bool),
    Char(char),
}

fn main() {
    let v: [Data; 3] = [Data::Usize(1), Data::Bool(true), Data::Char('a')];
}
```

### Solution 2 (flexible, supports almost any type)

```
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let v: [Box<dyn Any>; 3] = [Box::new(1), Box::new('a'), Box::new(true)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The very point of an `array` or a `Vec` is that they are homogenous, which also means each member needs to be the same size. But when given a `u8` and a `u128` - which are both `std::any::Any` - their sizes are not the same. One, therefore, needs a layer of indirection e.g. via `[Box<dyn std::any::Any>; _]` or `Vec<Box<std::any::Any>>`.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to Javascript, Rust is a strongly typed language. This means that any variable has a single type that is known at compile-time. This includes vector or array elements. You can work around this limitation by wrapping your data in an `enum` that will keep track of the actual type of the contained value at runtime.

Note that I strongly advise against using `Any` until you have lots of experience with Rust and know that your are using it for the right reason (and in particular **not** just to reproduce a pattern found in scripting languages.